# Is the following inequality in the form of integer linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Since I'm using an element of an array as an index of another array, is the following inequality still considered as ILP representation?

> $1 - M[s[i], s[k]] + M[s[i], s[j]] >= 1$

M and S are respectively 2d and 1d arrays and S's elements are in the range of M's indexes.

Comment: is $s$ fixed or part of the optimization problem?

Comment: It's part of the optimization problem.

Comment: please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 2):

It is not valid because $s$ is not constant. If $M$ is fixed, you can use $\sum_{i,j} M_{ij} x_{ij}$ with $x_{ij}$ binary to select elements of $M$. For example, you can model $M_{s_i,s_j}$ as $\sum_{i,j} M_{ij} x_{ij}$ by using the following constraints on $x_{ij}$ that ensure that only $x_{s_i,s_j}$ is $1$ and the other elements of $x_{ij}$ are $0$:
$$\sum_{i,j} i x_{ij} =s_i$$
$$\sum_{i,j} j x_{ij} =s_j$$
$$\sum_{i,j} x_{ij} =1$$
$$x_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$$